# VB6 erroring out with Runtime 5 with external library

Tags: vb6

We are using an external high resolution timer library that handles data acquisition. This timer came with a license file. For some reason, the timer library will intermittently complain about not finding the license file. This is when I *believe* the application errors out.

I was able to find this error by breaking on all errors.

Is there a way to debug this further, or am I stuck without the source code?

**EDIT:**

---

I just noticed that after compiling, I am getting a lot of Runtime 5 errors. This seems to happen more with a compied copy of the code than from within the IDE.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: It was a company called Mabry. It's called Mabry HiTime Timer

Comment: _**Invalid procedure call or argument** You passed an invalid parameter in your procedure call. This could be because the parameter was out of range, or contained invalid data. Alternately, you may have invoked a procedure at an unexpected time. To correct this error 
1. Verify that the parameters being passed to the procedure are valid. 
2. Verify that you are calling the function at an appropriate time._

Comment: Do you know whether it's the library or your code throwing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mabry has been gone a LONG time.

Perhaps try replacing the Timer library.  A quick google search has lots of results, this was the top one:

http://vb.mvps.org/tools/ccrpTmr/

> CCRP High Performance Timer Objects, created by CCRP member Karl E.
>   Peterson, provide much more robust options than Visual Basic's
>   intrinsic Timer control ever has. For years, the only option available
>   to VB developers was to add a form to their project if they wanted to
>   use a timer. This had the effect of totally destroying any hope of
>   encapsulation if, for example, a class module needed periodic timer
>   events

Comment: Thanks TC, I've downloaded that library and will try and replace the Mabry timer.